# How to configure nginx for Wordpress

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I've installed everything that is needed by Wordpress i.e. nginx 1.2.5 (built from source on **/usr/local/nginx**), php-fpm with other php packages and mysql via `apt-get`. I downloaded **wordpress-3.4.2.zip** and extracted it in **/usr/local/nginx/html/blog**. I've created MySQL database for wordpress with all privileges. When I visit **localhost/blog** from my browser I get *500 Internal server error*.

Is there any special configuration that needs to done in nginx for making Wordpress work?

Comment: Wordpress recommends this link(https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx) to setup nginx.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Easyengine: Its a one click nginx php5-fpm mysql and wordpress (Cache Support) setup scripts for Ubuntu

More About EasyEngine: http://rtcamp.com/easyengine/

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04). It's a tutorial on nginx/WordPress/Ubuntu 12.04. It should work with the latest versions of Ubuntu and WP but let me know if you encounter difficulties.
I think your problem is to do with nginx and the .htaccess file but I have no experience with nginx - only Apache - and the two work quite differently, as you can see over on Server Fault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/441346/nginx-what-is-the-equivalent-to-a2enmod).